# Image extraction from a URL using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, url, image-processing

I am trying to extract and save a google map image from the internet using a URL so as to try and extract some data out of it.

Appreciate any sort of suggestions or help regarding this matter.
Thanks !

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will significantly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Well for now I am trying to take a screen shot of a page by giving its URL in Matlab. The idea is to save this image and perform image enhancement on it later.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a URL of an image file into `imread`.  However, you cannot read in an html document as an image into MATLAB directly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ! I tried to do what u said, y = imread('https://www.google.co.in/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&authuser=0&biw=1366&bih=667&site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=gateway+of+india+wallpaper&revid=1090084629&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q1QIoAGoVChMIuLLUq-vcxgIVxXQ-Ch3LHgHP#imgrc=07-SMJdks15ktM%3A');    This doesn't seem to work. Matlab is unable to determine the file format. Am I making some kind of syntax error ?